# On the spectrum of a certain matrix

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, jacobian, stability-theory, fixed-points

I have a system of differential equations for which I want to find conditions under which a fixed point is stable or not. The system has the following parameters: $b_1, \ldots, b_K, g_1, \ldots, g_K$ and $(m_{lc})_{l, c = 1}^K$. The Jacobian matrix evaluated at the fixed point is given as follows:
\begin{equation}
J = 
\begin{pmatrix}
l b_1 - (g_1 + \sum_{c=1}^K m_{1c}) & m_{21} & \dots & m_{K1} \\
m_{12} & l b_2 - (g_2 + \sum_{c=1}^K m_{2c}) & \dots & m_{K2} \\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
m_{1K} & m_{2K} & \dots & l b_K - (g_K + \sum_{c=1}^K m_{Kc})
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}
I have applied Gershgorin's circle theorem to $J^T$ and derived the following property of the eigenvalues $\lambda^J$ of $J$:
\begin{equation}
|\lambda^J - (lb_s - (g_s + \sum_{l = 1}^K m_{sl}))| \leq \sum_{l=1}^K m_{sl}
\end{equation}
i.e.
\begin{equation}
\lambda^J \in [lb_s - (g_s + 2 \sum_{l=1}^K m_{sl}), lb_s - g_s]
\end{equation}
The fixed point will be stable if all eigenvalues are negative. Thus if the condition $l b_s - g_s < 0$ is satisfied, the fixed point will be stable.

Is my logic correct? And is there something else that I can apply?